# I have this jquery function...that slides up. I want it to slide left

Tags: jquery

Here's a working example of my function. Works as it should. However, how do I make it slide left, instead of sliding up/down?

http://jsfiddle.net/QWQYS/24/

Comment: What element(s) do you want to slide left?  The blue areas? The buttons?

Comment: In other words, each .panel class

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this:

```
$('.next').click(function () {
    $('.panel:visible').animate({ width: 'hide' }).closest('.panel').nextAll('.panel').eq(0).delay(500).animate({ width: 'show' });
});

$('.prev').click(function () {
    $('.panel:visible').animate({ width: 'hide' }).closest('.panel').prevAll('.panel').eq(0).delay(500).animate({ width: 'show' });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QWQYS/34/)

Of course you're elements are positioned relative, and the height on the container is dynamic, so it all looks really strange. You'll have to figure that out in your CSS.

Comment: Thanks. But this is the same as hide and showing a div using .show() & .hide() really. I want the entire panel to slide left with the next panel coming in from the right. Vice versa if you hit the prev button. Maybe with jQuery UI?